# hashes ruby merge

Tags: ruby, hash

My txt file contains a few lines and i want to add each line to a hash with key as first 2 words and value as 3rd word...The following code has no errors but the logic may be wrong...last line is supposed to print all the keys of the hash...but nothing happens...pls help

```
    def word_count(string)
        count = string.count(' ')
        return count
    end
    h = Hash.new


    f = File.open('sheet.txt','r')
    f.each_line do |line|
        count = word_count(line)
        if count == 3
            a = line.split
            h.merge(a[0]+a[1] => a[2])
        end
    end
    puts h.keys
```

Comment: Dont forget to accept mu's answer by clicking the green check mark.  And welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: You don't really need the word_count method.  `a.length` will tell you how many words there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge) doesn't modify the hash you call it on, it returns the merged Hash:

> **merge(other_hash) → new_hash**
>
> Returns a new hash containing the contents of *other_hash* and the contents of *hsh*. [...]

Note the *Returns a new hash...* part. When you say this:

```
h.merge(a[0]+a[1] => a[2])
```

You're merge the new values you built into a copy of `h` and then throwing away the merged hash; the end result is that `h` never gets anything added to it and ends up being empty after all your work.

You want to use [`merge!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) to modify the Hash:

```
h.merge!(a[0]+a[1] => a[2])
```

or keep using `merge` but save the return value:

```
h = h.merge(a[0]+a[1] => a[2])
```

or, since you're only adding a single value, just assign it:

```
h[a[0] + a[1]] = a[2]
```

Comment: This is probably the answer you're looking for.  +1

Comment: Remember that there's almost always a utility method for the kind of manipulation you want to do, so have a look through the extensive documentation on Hash, Array and Enumerable to know what's in your toolbox. There are hundreds of methods which can come in very handy, like `merge` is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the first three words of each line to the hash, regardless of how many words there are, then you can drop the `if count == 3` line. Or you can change it to `if count > 2` if you want to make sure that there are at least three words.

Also, mu is correct.  You'll want h.merge!

Comment: 4th word is for different purpose

Comment: and there are exactly four words, with no space after the fourth?

Comment: not exactly 4...could be less but not more...that's why i used
if count == 3

Comment: Pop quiz: what does `h.merge(...)` do?